# Use angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector() with karma + jasmine

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I have an angular 1 application that I am writing in a very custom style so that the switch to angular 2 is much more straight forward, so for example, not using `angular.service()` to create a service within angular and use the normal means of dependency injection, but instead creating a raw typescript (or ES2015 style) `class`. When running normally in a browser all of the following code runs without any issues.

The issue is with one line in particular:

```
Auth.jwtHelper = angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector().get('jwtHelper');
```

The error thrown in karma is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

So naturally that means that the injector isn't being located. Again, this absolutely works 100% when running normally in the browser. Also it is good to note that this line is being called upon instantiation of the service which happens on the jQuery DOM ready event `$(function{...});`

Module bootstrapping is done in the normal documented fashion of using `<html ng-app="myApp">` The `ng-app` directive could be moved to `<body>` as the application doesn't require scope in the `<head>` element as it did previously. Perhaps that's why karma is choking on this call.

*Update: Moving `ng-app` to `<body>` yielded no change*

I have dug through some of the angular mock source code and .d.ts files to try and find any alternative ways to get ahold of the injector for the application but haven't seen anything that I can use as of yet.

What I am looking for is *constructive* advice, alternatives that do not require use of angular's typical injection pattern, or any other tidbits that might be useful.

As expected, since this is a very non-typical approach, google results have not been very helpful.

**UPDATE:**

A little more context on the issue

```
export class Auth{
    public static jwtHelper;

    public static init(){
        Auth.jwtHelper = angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector().get('jwtHelper');
    }
}
$(Auth.init);
```

As you can see here the init method is called on DOM ready, not from a unit test. I can't provide a describe block of a unit test because this runs separate from my unit tests. It is part of the application loading.

Comment: Please, provide the context for this spec. It is not clear how module bootstrapping is being done in your case.

Comment: True, module bootstrapping is done using the `ng-app` attribute on the `<html>` element and letting angular auto-bootstrap the application.

Comment: Moving `ng-app` to `<body>` didn't seem to have any effect and I can't really go any lower down the tree as my `<body>` element has an `ng-class` that it needs for styling.

Comment: I mean what exactly happens in 'describe' block. And where do you load 'ngMock' module?

Comment: Normally you use ng-mock to inject the module in your test code. Please post the relevant Unit testing code.

Comment: @estus I have provided a little more context above but this doesn't actually happen during a unit test at all. This is on DOM ready, so I can't provide you with a describe block.

Comment: @GaneshKumar Your comment gave me an idea of something I could try, I could check and see if angular.mock is defined, if so then use the angular mock module loader. So that would be something like a ternary on the trouble line to either load the module through mocks, or through normal means

Comment: @GaneshKumar the ngMock module() and injector() functions are not synchronous. So ternary is out. Still trying to think of a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize it's a pretty old question but seeing that I just ran into the same issue, I figured I'd post my solution in there for the next guy.

What you need to do is monkey patch `angular.element` so it returns the injector:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(['$injector', function(injector) {
  // save original
  var original = angular.element;

  // replace with our own
  angular.element = function() {
    // proxy all calls to the original
    var result = original.apply(this, arguments);

    // add the injector to the result
    result.injector = function() { return injector; };
    return result;
  }

  // also add all the angular.element properties to our fake or some other stuff will break
  for (let prop in original) {
    angular.element[prop] = original[prop];
  }
}]));
```

Put that bit right after the `angular.mock.module()` declaration in your specs and you're good to go!

Comment: Awesome, I never solved the issue and just moved to Angular 2 instead. Hope this helps other people though.

Comment: Just mind to use this code after app initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and was able to solve this problem with the following...

Note: I'm using Typescript

```
let SampleController, $injector;

(<any>angular).mock.inject(($componentController, _$injector_) => {
     $injector = _$injector_;

     // angular.element(document.body).injector() doesn't behave correctly because we don't have ng-app in the DOM for unit tests. Spy the injector response instead.
     spyOn(angular.element.prototype, "injector").and.callFake(() => {
         return $injector;
     });

     // angular.element is triggered in the super of SampleController
     SampleController = $componentController("SampleComponent", null);
});
```

I think it's a bit more straightforward since you are focusing on the prototype of angular.element